# Text isn't properly centered?

Tags: html, css

I have my social menu `text-aligned:center` but it's still is off quite a ways. Here's my code and a jsfiddle to demonstrate the trouble. As you can see it has more open space on the left than right. I want to even it out.

*[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRvLn/)*

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        Erratic Fox
    </div>
    <div id="social">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://facebook.com/erraticfox">Facebook</a></li> —
        <li><a href="http://erratic-fox.deviantart.com">Deviant Art</a></li> —
        <li><a href="http://youtube.com/erraticfox">YouTube</a></li> —
        <li><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/erraticfox">Steam</a></li>
    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

#header {
    color: #404040;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size:100px;
    text-align: center;
}

#social {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#social a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #404040;
    transition: 1s color;
    -moz-transition: 1s color;
    -webkit-transition: 1s color;
}

#social a:hover {
    color: #427FED;
    transition: 1s color;
    -moz-transition: 1s color;
    -webkit-transition: 1s color;
}

#social li {
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: That's not really valid markup. I don't believe you should have content within a <ul> that is not within a <li>.

Comment: -1 because that's basic stuff. Every browser has a set of default styles and you didn't reset the padding of the `ul`

Comment: Exactly, it's the ul padding that is giving you trouble. I think you should start using Firebug ;)

Comment: @Prinzhorn how is that basic when compared to a guy who barely knows anything about browser has a set of default styles? I think it's unfair that you think *everbody* would know about something like that even if they're a early student in HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Prinzhorn There are plenty of Stack Overflow questions about user agent styles that aren't voted down. Some people might not consider it "basic", but assuming it is, how is that justification for a downvote? Everyone starts learning somewhere. Stack Overflow welcomes people of all experience levels, and there was obviously effort put into this question.

Comment: @ajp15243 what if they was never told about user agent styles or default browser styles?

Comment: @ErraticFox That's kind of my point with "all experience levels" and "Everyone starts learning somewhere". Downvotes are not meant for punishing lack of knowledge, otherwise the entire point of this site is defeated.

Comment: I can't remove the down vote anymore. It's just that these types of question are the reason I went away from other forums to StackOverflow. Of course everyone has to start _somewhere_, but that doesn't mean every beginner should post on StackOverflow if he or she gets stuck a tiny little bit. But I will think twice before down voting next time!

Comment: @Prinzhorn I think that's a good stance. [Downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) are meant to be for "extreme cases" (see last section). If there are other questions like a given question, then it's usually best to link to those duplicates and perhaps flag the question as a duplicate, as an alternative to downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
#social ul {
  padding-left:0;
}
```

[***Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/AvhA3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this:

```
ul { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```